# Python Tk: Can't Retrieve Dice Roll Integer for Calculations

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, dice

For my final project in an intro course to Python, I've got to create a game of Pig (the dice game) using a GUI.

I'm try to create a single die roll and record that information so that I can retrieve it and calculate the turn score and the total score. The problem is, I can't figure out how to store the die roll information and retrieve it so I can make those calculations. As it stands, I'm storing the information within the label itself and trying to retrieve it from there, but I can't do calculations unless it's an integer. Labels, from what I'm to understand, work only with text and images.

Here's the code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from random import *


class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        self.headerFont = ("courier new", "16", "bold")

        self.title("Pig, The Dice Game")
        self.headers()
        self.playerTurn()
        self.getTurnScore()

    def headers(self):
        Label(self, text = "Instructions", font = self.headerFont).grid(columnspan = 4)
        Label(self, text = "Text", font = self.headerFont).grid(row = 1, columnspan = 4)

        Label(self).grid(row = 1, columnspan = 4)
        Label(self, text = "The Game of Pig", font = self.headerFont).grid(row = 2, columnspan = 4)

    def playerTurn(self):
        self.btnRoll = Button(self, text = "Roll The Die")
        self.btnRoll.grid(row = 3, columnspan = 2)
        self.btnRoll["command"] = self.calculateRoll

        Label(self, text = "You Rolled:").grid(row = 4, column = 0)
        self.lblYouRolled = Label(self, bg = "#fff", anchor = "w", relief = "groove")
        self.lblYouRolled.grid(row = 4, column = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = "we")

        Label(self, text = "Options:").grid(row = 5, column = 0)
        self.lblOptions = Label(self, bg = "#fff", anchor = "w", relief = "groove")
        self.lblOptions.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = "we")

        Label(self, text = "Turn Score:").grid(row = 6, column = 0)
        self.lblTurnScore = Label(self, bg = "#fff", anchor = "w", relief = "groove")
        self.lblTurnScore.grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = "we")

        Label(self, text = "Total Score").grid(row = 7, column = 0)
        self.lblTotalScore = Label(self, bg = "#fff", anchor = "w", relief = "groove")
        self.lblTotalScore.grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = "we")


    def calculateRoll(self):
        self.roll = randint(1,6)

        #self.lblYouRolled["text"] = roll

    def getTurnScore(self):
        #self.lblTurnScore["text"] =


def main():
  app = App()
  app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting your roll information with `self.roll = randint(1,6)`. You can append it to a list. Then use it as you like.

```
self.all_rolls = [] #if you dont want to get an empty list each button click, you might want to make this definition under __init__
self.roll = randint(1,6)
self.all_rolls.append(self.roll)
#to use your rolls, you can iterate over that list
for item in self.all_rolls:
   print (item)  #this is just for an example ofcourse
```

Since I don't know how the game works, this is all I can help.
By the way, labels can show integers also. So your line works fine if you add `self.`.

```
self.lblYouRolled["text"] = self.roll
```

**EDIT**:

```
from random import *
summ = 0
all_rolls = [1,2,3]
roll = randint(1,6)
all_rolls.append(roll)

for die_roll in all_rolls:
    summ += die_roll

print ("Roll:",roll," Total sum",summ)
```

I ran above code twice and these are the outputs.

```
>>> Roll: 2  Total sum: 8

>>> Roll: 4  Total sum: 10
```

Comment: That makes sense, and I think it's the right way to go, but I'm getting an error:




**"AttributeError: 'list' object attribute 'append' is read-only"**

Comment: Dont use _list_ as a variable name. Try something else because _list_ is a built-in class.

Comment: Oh, I'm not, I'm actually using the same names you used because they make sense.

Comment: Anything have you done additional to this code? Because this works fine for me.

Comment: Yep, just realized I'd done something stupid. Rather than have self.all_rolls.append(self.roll) I had self.all_rolls.append = (self.roll).

Couldn't tell you why I added the "gets" symbol.

Though I am having an odd problem now with adding the contents of the list together. For some reason it isn't adding it properly.

Comment: It wouldn't work, so I isolated the issue in a new module just to test it.

I created a list of integers:  **[1,2,3] and appended [4]**.
Then I tried to add them together thusly: **print addList[0+1+2]** and came up with 4 rather than 6, as it should be. [0+0] is spitting out as 1, rather than 2. Trying to do [0+1+2+3] is spitting out an error that it's out of range.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you are saying. Please look at the edit. You need to iterate over all items to sum up all. Not something like `[0+1+...]`

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Nice job as always with your Tk answers :p